# Get the count of A -> B and B->A without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like so:

```
index|from | to
------------------
  1  | ABC | DEF
  2  | ABC | GHI
  3  | ABC | GHI
  4  | ABC | JKL
  5  | ABC | JKL
  6  | ABC | JKL
  7  | DEF | ABC
  8  | DEF | GHI
  9  | DEF | JKL
 10  | GHI | ABC
 11  | GHI | ABC
 12  | GHI | ABC
 13  | JKL | DEF
```

And I need to count how the total times between the points (regardless of direction) to get the result:

```
 A  |  B  | count
-----------------
ABC | DEF | 2
ABC | GHI | 5
ABC | JKL | 3
DEF | GHI | 1
DEF | JKL | 2
```

So far I can get:

```
SELECT `a`.`from` as `A`, `a`.`to` as `B`, (`a`.`count` + `b`.`count`) as `count`
FROM
(SELECT `from`, `to`, count(*) as `count`  
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY 1,2) `a`
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT `from`,`to`, count(*) as `count`  
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY 1,2) `b`
ON `a`.`from` = `b`.`to` 
AND `a`.`to` = `b`.`from`
```

But I'm unsure how to remove the A/B swapped duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select `from` as A, `to` as B, count(*) as `count`
from your_table
group by if (from<to, concat(from,to), concat(to,from));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'from' as first, 'to' as second
FROM 'table'
UNION
SELECT 'to' as first, 'from' as second
FROM 'table'
```

That will give you all of the pairs, forward and back.  To eliminate the duplicates you just need a WHERE clause that imposes order on first and second.

```
SELECT first, second, count(*)
FROM (
SELECT 'from' as first, 'to' as second
FROM 'table'
UNION
SELECT 'to' as first, 'from' as second
FROM 'table'
) x
WHERE first < second
GROUP BY first, second
```

It's simpler to avoid keywords for your field and table names; you can leave the quotes off.